# Hotel management database

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a standalone app with C# and MSSQL. 
The problem come from SQL database.
I want to manage orderid of room, example: Room number A01 order one beer and two cakes. How can i create database to save this information?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can setup a 1:n relation between rooms and orders. Other than that, your question is pretty vague. Add some details if you want more help.

Comment: @AlexTartan Thank you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have table room_orders(room_id, product_id, product_count and date if you want). Besides that you should have tables rooms and products with description of the room and product.

Comment: Thanks you! Have a nice day!